# My Javascript only works in FireFox, why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a,b){
  var div=document.getElementById(a);
  var button=document.getElementById(b);
  if(!div)return true;
    if(div.style.display=="block"){
      div.style.display="none"
      button.value="Expand"
    }
  else{
    div.style.display="block"
    button.value="Shrink"
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
<div id="para1" class="toggleMe">
    <p>"Text Blob"</p>
</div>
<input id="para1button" onclick="return toggleMe('para1','para1button')" type="button" value="Expand" />
```

The above is my script, and it only works in Firefox.  I've googled myself silly, but I can't figgure out why its only working in FF.

Anyone got any hints?

If you want to see the exact implementation, its here:
http://www.techonline.co.nz/modules/navigator/navto.php?unique_ID=16

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined `

Comment: If you want to see if `e` isn't defined, try something like this instead: `if (typeof e === 'undefined') return true;`

Comment: Sorry, just found where you mean.  I had edited my code to make it more readable.  the var div, used to be var e.

Comment: This appears to work for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/hrEDc/

Comment: Blender's little fix made it work in Chrome.  Thank you :)  I don't have IE (I use Linux) but ill post again when I have a chance to test it from IE.

Again, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the e, it works in most browsers.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>toggle display</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a,b){
    var div= document.getElementById(a);
    var button= document.getElementById(b);
    if(div.style.display== "block"){
        div.style.display= "none"
        button.value= "Expand"
    }
    else{
        div.style.display= "block"
        button.value= "Shrink"
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
<div id="para1" style="display:none">
    <p>"Text Blob"</p>
</div>
<input id="para1button" onclick="toggleMe('para1','para1button')" type="button" value="Expand">

</body>
</html>
```